# How to monitor the progress of training a classifier?

Tags: monitoring, machine-learning

I've had `p = Predict[x -> y]` running for hours and I have now idea if I should kill it or not.

I'm looking for some rough bounds for an estimate of how long `Predict[]` or `Classify[]` will take to train depending on the size of the input and the method used:

- "LinearRegression"
- "NearestNeighbors"
- "RandomForest"
- "NeuralNetwork"

Would be really helpful to monitor the loss function like you can in other ML systems.

Answer (score 13):

This is on our list of planned functionality.

For now, you can estimate the run time by training on a smaller set first, and then extrapolating.

Comment: In 10.3 or 11? what would a rough time estimate be? Also the run time would be problem specific, can you show an example with code maybe?